# How to retrieve datetime from database in Drupal?

Tags: database, datetime

How do I retrieve a DateTime column from my MySQL database using Drupal Database API + PHP. The DateTime format is in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS(2013-02-20 23:59:59). I want to retrieve all the rows in the database that match a specific date, and then store the hour inside an array.

For example, I want to grab all the data from January 1, 2013. I then only want to store hours 00:00 to 23:59 inside my array, not the entire date.

I do not want to use any modules to accomplish this.. because I need to code it inside my custom module.

Thanks for your help!

Current Code:

```
$query = db_select('Project', 'p');
$query->fields('p', array('submissions', 'date_time'));
$query->condition('p.user_id', $user->uid);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $r) {
    $rows[] = array(strtotime(date("H:i:s", $r->date_time))*1000, $r->submissions);
}
```

I plan to display the data on my Flot line graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the benefits of a `SelectQuery`, but with the more fine-grained control over the SQL, you can always use the `where()` method to inject (sanitised) raw SQL into the `WHERE` clause. e.g

```
$query = db_select('Project', 'p');
$query->fields('p', array('submissions', 'date_time'));
$query->condition('p.user_id', $user->uid);

// Fetch only records where date_time is greater than 30 days ago
$query->where('date_time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)');

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $r) {
  $rows[] = array(strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $r->date_time))*1000, $r->numberOfPackages);
}
```

I don't know of any 'structured' way to get those sort of advanced conditions into a `SelectQuery` object so resorting to plain ol' SQL is necessary sometimes.

Comment: I know this question is more PHP related but... after retrieving the rows with the matching date, do you know how to format it so that I only store the Hour:Minutes:Seconds in my array?

Comment: `date('H:i:s', $r->date_time)` should do the trick - there's a list of all the available formats in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) if you're interested

Answer (score -1):

The code below works for me for fetching a group, so you can quickly adapt it for your own purpose.

```
$query = db_select('og')
    ->fields('og', array('etid'))
    ->condition('gid', $gid,'=');
$results = $query->execute();

$result = $results->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question...